# Launch app into foreground with PushKit / voip

Tags: ios

My app is registered for background modes: Voice over IP, Background fetch and Remote Notifications.

I successfully receive voip push notifications with the code below, but I am unable to launch the app to receive the call.  How can I launch the app without any user interaction when the voipPush is received?

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

var voipRegistry:PKPushRegistry!
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
    print("VOIP Push registered")

    return true
}

func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    let voipToken: String! = credentials.token.description
    print("\n\n##### PushKit credential: \n\n", voipToken)
}

func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    let data = payload.dictionaryPayload
    print("\n\n##### Received PushKit Data: \n\n", data)
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let videocallViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("videocallViewController")
    window!.rootViewController = videocallViewController

}
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution here?

Comment: @johannes Yeah. Short is answer you can't launch from the background unless you have asked for and been given permission for UIUserNotification [.Alert] and the user accepts the notification.

Comment: Could you post an answer with code? :) Thanks! Asking for permission is not a problem in my case, I expect most users to accept (enterprise app)

Comment: @johannes Hi, just read your request now.. do you still need it ?

Comment: I think I understand now :) The user has to interact with the local notification you send from the background to enter the foreground? I wonder how skype does it without any local notification, they manage to open the "call screen" without any further interaction

Comment: Never mind, I just double checked, skype has got the same problem ..

Comment: @johannes Yep, exactly ;-) sorry for late response

Comment: Skype re-promts you for notifications permission if you initially decline.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that skype was able to enter foreground without the local notification, seems they are not ... This is actually so much better on Android I have to admit

Comment: @johannes Yeah, I can imagine. In our app we can only present the "incomingCallVC" directly if the app is already in the foreground. Otherwise we have to rely on the notification, which admittedly you can have play a 30sec ringtone and with (only) one vibration. It works well if the user expects the call, not so well if calls happen "randomly".

Comment: @johannes Out of curiosity, do you use a dedicated notification service, or will you set it up yourself with certificates etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99945/discussion-between-johannes-and-karlml).

Comment: i need to trigger call kit itself is much more better tell if any to trigger call kit in objective c, now the call kit example was in iOS swift as this example was working fine when i trigger VOIP push into ... example (speakerBox) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html